# Three computers accessing internet but only two network interfaces showing in ´ifconfig´, why?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, ifconfig, network-interface

My gateway(router) is connected to DSL.

The gateway connects to 1 wireless transceiver device. 2 fixed computers connect to the router. At the moment of me doing ifconfig 2 fixed computers were connected to the internet. And 1(my laptop) computer was accessing wireless internet. Yet when I do `ifconfig` I can only see 2 network interfaces: `eth0` and `eth1`(and `lo`).

Why don't I see 3 network interfaces when I have 3 different internet connections?

Comment: You are running command on computer or router?

Comment: I am running the command from my laptop.

Comment: From your laptop, after SSHing to router? If not, don't expect that it'd display router things...

Comment: I didn't know that before. SSHing to router, is that like port forwarding safely?

Comment: SSHing to router means running commands natively on router.. Not on computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand correctly. But you have 1 Wireless gateway and 3 Devices connected to it?

So doing [ifconfig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifconfig) only shows PHYSICAL hardware/connections on the PC that ran the command - not the connections available or other device.

> ifconfig stands for interface configuration

- An interface if a virtual or physical layer on the computer that enables it to communicate with other devices using a standard, for example in your case TCP/IP
- `eth0` could be your Wired Network card running at 10/100/1000
- `eth1` is possibly your wirless interface running at a/b/g/n speeds.
- `lo` is a virtual interface and is called a loopback and bind to your computer using home (127.0.0.1) or (localhost) or whatever your computers name is(because it loops back to it self)

To see other computers you need to use something like [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) and to find other computers or devices within your network range.

Also as suggested you can use a wireless tool [iwconfig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iwconfig) to scan for access points (an access point is not an interface- but the access point it self uses an interface to communicates with other devices found in ARP)

And you only have 1 internet connection, not 3.

**In total you should have 5 ARP entries - 2 PC's, 1Notebook, 1Switch and 1 Modem**

[image]

So as you can see in the illustration, each host has an interface of eth0, the gateway has eth0 and the ISP on the other side has eth0. the more interfaces a device has the higher the number.

Comment: In addition to this, isn't iwconfig for wireless connections?

Comment: Interfaces don't have to be physical -- many are not (`lo`, vlan interfaces, vpn interfaces, virtual interfaces, interfaces created to network virtual machines)

Comment: What is the ARP command to see all the other devices on your network?

Answer (score 2):

`ifconfig` shows you **interfaces**. I.e., you might see an entry for each wired (physical)  connection, and one for your wireless.

What `ifconfig` does **not** show you is **connections**. You might be serving hundreds of file transfers to as many connected systems via ethernet, and you would still only see that one ethernet card in `ifconfig`.

Answer (score 2):

ARP for windows

> arp -a

[image]

ARP in most linux/unix/bsd distros

> arp-scan --interface=eth0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have this setup;

```
           <ISP>
             |
      <Router Machine>
             |
         <Switch>
      /      |      \
Machine 1  Machine 2 WiFi AP
```

If that's the case of course ifconfig will only show two interfaces.. because you only have two interfaces.

Comment: Where is the answer?

Comment: "because you only have two interfaces."

Comment: its obvios the OP does not undestand what ifconfig does. not the number of interfaces displayed. How do you know he has only 2 interfaces? because he wrote that in his question. congratulations on cyclic redundancy reticulation of rhetorically answering his  questions.

Comment: We know he has two interfaces because ifconfig says so (2 interfaces that are up at least). Which means he must have some other device in the mix.. which is probably a switch. You seem to be upset that you wrote a long answer that isn't really needed. The answer to "Why does ifconfig only show two interfaces?" is "Because you only have two" and the diagram explains exactly why that is the case. I guess you downvoted my answer in some sort of childish revenge for being more succinct than you.

Comment: i downvoted you because your answer is not helpful and ascii art is over rated. maybe you should join a BBS. An answer should be constructive just like the question, linked to good resources and use modern day techniques.. like Images. After your comment it was clear to me that you had no intent in making your answer any more helpful and I thought you deserved a downvote for being slightly lazy and arrogant.

Comment: >maybe you should join a BBS. -- Really? Maybe you shouldn't answer unix questions. Go look at the PF manual, its full of ascii art.

Comment: @ppumkin: Downvoting because he used ASCII art instead of an image? **Really?**

Comment: @DevSolar Not because of ASCII art- I grew up making ASCII menus for DOS while my IT teacher picked his nose. I downvoted him because his answers was neither helpful nor constructive. If his ASCII art answered the questoin then fine- i would have upvoted him- But my answer was picked as correct and even answeres after mine are upvoted more times than user1104505 's - So its not just me. His answer is terrible.

Comment: @ppumkin: His answer is factually correct and sufficiently thought-provoking, just less hand-holding or elaborate than yours. If you don't consider it worthy of an upvote, fine, but your downvote, and incidentally your attitude, is out of place IMHO.

Comment: @DevSolar Well this very forum systems architecture encourages users to downvote a "not so good" answer and give the person a chance to edit and improve his answer.. allowing me to revoke my decision and possibly up-vote him. So.....if he does not want to I cannot make him.

Comment: @ppumkin the only person that has an issue with my answer is you.. I don't really mind but if I took your attitude I would go and down vote all of your answers for being unnecessarily verbose and overuse of images. Your answer also contains at least one mistake/inconsistency (you googled what ifconfig does opposed to actually knowing what it does?) that could have been avoided had you not tried to answer questions that had not been asked.

Comment: Yes, I am entitled to opinion as are you. Googe'ling allot of these questions comes back to SE in top order. It is good for people who do not know the answer and get several well constructed and well opinionated answers, then it makes SE owners allot of bucks from advertising.. but keeps up bickering because we might not feel entirely satisfied with what others have answered or commented about them.